# Why isn't Admin detecting these models?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm making a kanban app to learn Django, and I've run into this problem: Admin doesn't pick up the models I've created.

I had an existing Postgresql database with the necessary tables created, and autogenerated the models with `python manage.py inspectdb`.

These are the relevant models:

```py
class Boards(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "boards"


class Columns(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    board = models.ForeignKey(Boards, models.CASCADE, db_column="board")

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "columns"


class Cards(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    description = models.TextField()
    deadline = models.DateTimeField()
    column = models.ForeignKey("Columns", models.CASCADE, db_column="column")

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "cards"
```

And this is the content of `admin.py`:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Boards, Columns, Cards

admin.site.register(Boards)
admin.site.register(Columns)
admin.site.register(Cards)
```

Just in case, these are the `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "rest_framework",
]
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you haven't added your app name in **INSTALLED_APPS**,
after which you should do **manage.py makemigrations** and migrate